# How to create a soundfile from fft-spectrum with Python?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

Let's say I have a sound file (file1.wav) which is 1s long.
I can read it in via

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
samplerate, data = wavfile.read("file1.wav")
```

I can then fourier-transform it via:

```
from scipy.fft import fft
yf=fft(data)
```

Now lets say I have another file2 which contains a sound as well which does not have the same duration as file1 (it might also have another samplerate).

Now I would like to create a sound from the spectrum *yf* which is as long as the file2 and add both.

***How can I compute a sound from file1 with the samplerate and duration from file2 in order to be able to add both?***

Comment: I looked into: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/47640/generating-a-timeseries-with-an-arbitrary-power-spectrum but here the size of the outputfile cannot be chosen freely.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the essential question here is "how do I stretch/compress audio to another duration". This is a nontrivial task, there isn't a silver bullet method that works well in all cases. See [Audio time stretching and pitch scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_time_stretching_and_pitch_scaling) on Wikipedia. It matters what kind of audio you are operating on: speech, music, vs. something else.

A decent place to start is waveform-similarity-based synchronized overlap-add or WSOLA algorithm. One way to perform WSOLA is with the free [SoX command line utility](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) using its "tempo" effect:

> Change the audio playback speed but not its pitch. This effect uses the WSOLA algorithm. The audio is chopped up into segments which are then shifted in the time domain and overlapped (cross-faded) at points where their waveforms are most similar as determined by measurement of ‘least squares’.

Example use:

```
sox infile.wav outfile.wav tempo -s 1.1
```

where the `1.1` means "speed up by 10%" and the `-s` configures for speech (other options are `-m` for music or `-l` for generic "linear" processing). There are other options besides this, [check out the documentation](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) for more detail.

(Side note: A related problem is pitch shifting audio without changing the duration. SoX can do that too; see the "pitch" and "bend" effects.)

If you want to perform time stretching in Python, there is a [pysox](https://pysox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library that wraps SoX. Another possibility in Python is [audiotsm](https://audiotsm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which implements WSOLA and a couple other time stretching methods.